# Objective C round number to a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to round a number to another number (in my case x*90) and after some searching around I got it working thanks to this piece of code:

```
round(number / 90) * 90;
```

The question is if this is the best way to do it? It just feels like some trial/error code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the right way of doing it. If you were rounding doubles, you should use an `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
float roundedValue = round(number / 90) * 90;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]];
```

Comment: Thank you :) But what's the use of the NSNumberFormatter? Only to change the x.xxxx to x.x? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RickvanderLinde `NSNumberFormatter` allows you to determine the way the number is represented. There are tons of options (locale, currency signs...). Check the documentation for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number is an integer

```
((number + (90/2))/90) * 90;
```

If you want to use round() and friends you have to convert to floating point. The above does it all with integers. In any case many ways to do this (in your example the return will be a float, but an integral sized one.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I was dealing with a float. But I didn't know about this method for integers. Thanks :)

Comment: For floats lots of utilities - in Terminal type "man 3 math". Most if not all of those functions are in iOS.